# How to perform a more elegant filtering in Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

I would like to know the opinion and maybe there is a more beautiful, easier and more elegant way to do what I want.

I have an API that returns some reports about persons, it is used by more users.
There is a `GET /persons` endpoint that returns the list of persons.

It is required to make another `POST` endpoint `/persons/restrictions` that will have the `identityNumbers` in body and restricted: `true` or `false`, respectively in the next accesses for reports not to take into account the persons with `identityNumber` that have been sent in `POST /persons/restrictions` with restricted: `true`.

It does not seem fair to me to save all `identityNumber` and client in an table and at each request to search in that table for check if person restricted for this client or no.
What if will be more that 1000 records in that table.

When I make a report for `identityNumber` I will have to check that it is `NOT IN (select identityNumber from restrictionTable where client = clientId)` but for `IN` no more than 1000 possible cases are accepted ...

How can I perform such filtering for more `clients` and `person identityNumber`?

After a while at `POST /persons/restrictions` the list with `identityNumbers` can be sent to include them back in the reports

I will be grateful for any article or advice.

[Table persons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyHv9.png)

[POST /persons/restrictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCpD6.png)

multiple users can set the limit for different identityNumbers

Comment: `It is required to make another POST endpoint` makes no sense, is it making a new endpoint? and this part `respectively in the next accesses for reports not to take into account the persons with identityNumber that have been sent in POST /persons/restrictions with restricted: true.` Makes no sense, please provide code examples what you mean. Do NOT describe your code, show us your code.

Comment: I added the pictures, I hope it is clearer

Comment: Dont add images of code, its against the SO rules, please read the rules BEFORE posting